# “Does the university have” or “Does the university has”?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I do self-study for some English exam and this is a sentence from some online resource, which I suppose to listen and write down.

```
"Does the university have an ice-hockey team?"
```

In my opinion, since the university is singular, the word `'have'` should be replaced with `'has'`.

Please enlight me if I am wrong.

Comment: You would say (1) *It* ***has*** *one hockey team*, and (2) *It* ***has*** *two hockey teams*. Similarly, you would say (1) *Does it* ***have*** *one hockey team?*, and (2) *Does it* ***have*** *two hockey teams?* The singularly or plurality of the object makes no difference.

Comment: The construction is "Does [subject] [infinitive]". The infinitive is not conjugated; only the "helping verb" *do* is conjugated to agree with the subject. Likewise, we say "The university *does* **have** an ice-hockey team", "Will the university **have** an ice-hockey team?", "The university *will* **have** an ice-hockey team", "Did the university **have** an ice-hockey team?", "The university *did* **have** an ice-hockey team."

Comment: @sumelic I see, I wasn't careful enough to see that. I'll delete my comment with the "supposed" duplicate question, as it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the university have an ice-hockey team?

The sentence is grammatical; it's not correct to use has instead.

You can use "has" in an affirmative sentence as follows:

The university has an ice-hockey team.

But you don't use "has" with the auxiliary verb do, does or did in an interrogative or negative sentence; you always use the root form of the verb i.e. "have".  Another example:

Does Kushan goes to university?

The sentence is not correct. The noun Kushan is singular third person.  Even then you don't use "goes"; you use "go" instead.

Comment: Such a great explanation. Only your example also good enough for a person to understand the theory behind this. Thank you.